# SQL Query to check all the plugins deployed in OIM

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I have to check what all plugins are deployed in my all the environments of OIM.
I can do MDS export to check the same.

But I need a quicker solution to do the same.

Is there a SQL query to check the same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using following SQL:

```
select name,zipid from plugins;
```